# Meteor unable to open database and uninstallation failed

Tags: javascript, linux, meteor

(repost from meteor forum)

a random error occurred today when I tried to run my Meteor apps. I tried all the meteor commands such as meteor update, meteor, meteor create newApp, etc. Every time the errors says : SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file. I tried the solution by changing ownership of the file but it still doesn't work: sudo chown -R whales ~/.meteor.

So I decided to just uninstall meteor and reinstall it. However when I uninstalled it by running the two commands:

rm -rf ~/.meteor/
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/meteor

Both commands ran into the problem of can't remove read only file system.

Totally stuck...thanks for the help..

Edit:
I used linux Ubuntu. And this is the screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that your system is experiencing a filesystem consistency issue? Check `dmesg` to see if you have any filesystem errors.

Comment: @MasterAM I think you might be right. When I restarted it, it asked me to do fsck manually. After I ran that command I was able to restart the laptop and the error was gone.  I don't really know anything about these but thanks for the help!!